# excluding code from executing in commented part of the file

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing Perl script to execute on C code
I want to exclude my code from running inside comments(/* and */)

for this i am using flag and i set flag = 1 when (/* ) is encountered and flag = 0 when (*/) is encountered

MY CODE

```
my $input = $ARGV[0]; 
my $flag = 0;

while(<>){
   if($_ =~ "/*" ){
      $flag = 1; 
      }

   if($_ =~ "*/"){
      $flag = 0;
       }
if($flag == 0){
    #execute other code
    }

}
```

But i doesn't work. it is considering all lines to have /*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the regular expressions you're using have *s in them, and you'll need to escape them.  Try:

```
$flag = 0;
while(<>){

   if($_ =~ /\/\*/ ){
      $flag = 1; 
   }

   if($_ =~ /\*\//){
      $flag = 0;
   }

   if($flag == 0) {
       execute other code
   }

}
```

Your pasted code also had a missing closing bracket, by the way, which
I also fixed.

Comment: thanks . works fine. My actual code is quite big so i just wrote a small code to get idea of how to get it work. thing that i wanted was to exclude my code from doing any modification inside commented code

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
my $input = $ARGV[0]; 
my $flag = 0;

while(<>){
   if($_ =~ "\Q/*\E" ){
      $flag = 1; 
      }

   if($_ =~ "\Q*/\E"){
      $flag = 0;
       }
if($flag == 0){
    #execute other code
    }

}
```

Anything between \Q and \E is treated as plain text, all RegEx special chars are ignored.

Alternate: Use quotemeta (see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html ) if you RegEx isn't fixed but a dynamic value.